# Посоветуйте архитектуру и инструменты под следующую логику приложения

Tags: python, архитектура

Есть потребность в написании чат-бота (Viber, Telegram). Язык использую Python. Логика работы следующая:

1. Одни пользователи вводят данные через бота
2. Данные должны сохраняться
3. Другие пользователи должны эти данные тут же получать в месенджер, по событию добавления данных из пункта 1, НО с определенной фильтрацией. Т.е. для одного человека интересно одно, для другого - другое

Сказать по правде логика достаточно тривиальна, но вот с ее реализацией у меня честно сказать прям ступор. Логика похожа на паттерн Pub/Sub. Ступор конкретно возникает с хранением данных, а еще больше с их выборкой.

Как я себе представляю архитектуру:

1. Сервер принимает сообщение-запрос от месенджера (от пользователя, назовем этого пользователя Потребитель) - этот запрос грубо говоря фильтр, по которому этот же потребитель в дальнейшем хочет получать сообщения (отфильтрованную информацию) от бота, загруженную другим пользователем (назовем этого пользователя Продюсер)
2. Запись данных в БД. Тут у меня начинаются вопросы. Сообщение-запрос (фильтр) от потребителя нужно сохранить и далее по нему сопоставлять (делать выборку из БД) с данными которые уже есть от продюсеров. Сообщение-запрос (фильтр) естественно может быть как по другим параметрам, а может быть идентичный - другой такой же потребитель может составить точно такой же запрос. Группировать одинаковые как вариант? Это по логике получается что-то вроде канала уже.
3. Как тогда привязывать данные от продюсера в канал потребителя? Фильтровать каждое сообщение от продюсера по условиям и запихивать его в канал? Но дело  в том что одно и то же сообщение от продюсера может подходить под множество разных условий - запихивать сообщение в разные каналы? Каналов тогда будут тысячи, т.е. каждый канал соответствует какому-то определенному набору условий (но это как-то бредово по-моему выглядит). Тут тогда еще получается что каждый потребитель подписан на несколько каналов
4. Воркер-наблюдатель за каналами - по событию появления новой инфы в канале, делаем рассылку по потребителям

Это были мои мысли. Прошу помощи, как бы сделали это Вы, ну или как подобное вообще делается, с таким сталкиваюсь впервые. Какие инструменты посоветуете?